# Invalid numeric literal when running jq from script via crontab

Tags: linux, shell, curl, cron, jq

I have a shell script that runs fine from the command line but throws a error when it's run from a cronjob. What could be causing this error?

The following includes the cron, the script, and the error I'm getting in /var/spool/mail.

```
[jira-svc ~]$ cat jira_trigger_updater.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

tmp_file=/tmp/merge-issues/$(date --iso-8601=minutes).txt
mkdir -p /tmp/merge-issues

/usr/bin/curl -s -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://services-gateway.g054.usdcag.aws.ray.com/project-management/rest/api/2/search?jql=filter%3D14219&fields=key,status,fixVersions" -u jira-svc:${UPDATE_TRIGGER_PASSWORD} > ${tmp_file}
/usr/bin/jq -r '.issues[] | [.key , .fields.status.name , .fields.fixVersions[].name] | join(",")' ${tmp_file} > /rational/triggers/inputs/jira_merge.csv

/usr/bin/chmod 644 /rational/triggers/inputs/jira_merge.csv

#rm -rf /tmp/merge-issues
[jira-svc ~]$ crontab -l
#*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/jira-svc/jira_trigger_updater.sh
[jira-svc@ ~]$ tail -25 /var/spool/mail/jira-svc
From jira-svc@cc01-217-136.localdomain  Tue Feb  8 20:10:02 2022
Return-Path: <jira-svc@cc01-217-136.localdomain>
X-Original-To: jira-svc
Delivered-To: jira-svc@cc01-217-136.localdomain
Received: by cc01-217-136.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 1001)
        id 9C40168152B5; Tue,  8 Feb 2022 20:10:02 +0000 (UTC)
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <jira-svc@cc01-217-136.localdomain>
To: jira-svc@cc01-217-136.localdomain
Subject: Cron <jira-svc@cc01-217-136> /usr/bin/sh /home/jira-svc/jira_trigger_updater.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=2172>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/jira-svc>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=jira-svc>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=jira-svc>
Message-Id: <20220208201002.9C40168152B5@cc01-217-136.localdomain>
Date: Tue,  8 Feb 2022 20:10:02 +0000 (UTC)

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 13, column 0

[jira-svc ~]$
```

Comment: Is the variable `${UPDATE_TRIGGER_PASSWORD}` set correctly for the user performing the cronjob? You could make another job echoing it somewhere to test it.

Comment: Interesting, that was it. I have that variable defined in jira-svc's ~/.bashrc but cron wasn't picking it up. I solved this by sourcing /home/jira-svc/.bashrc at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` and you're sourcing `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Ya probably not correct although I think most of the systems I'm on symlink sh to bash anyways /shrug

Answer (score 0):

Cron runs jobs from a non-ineractive, non-login shell and doesn't load environment variables from files like `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, and others. You must source these files if you want to include the environment variables defined in them.